# What is SMIL? And what is its position in the architecture?

Tags: javascript, smil

I want to know what exactly is SMIL? I mean why its required and how they can be integrated into a javascript application.
In an application architecture whats the position of it? What is its significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend: the first hit is

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronized_Multimedia_Integration_Language

Comment: ya, I saw that but it doesn't answer all my questions. Ya , it gives the initial understandings.

Comment: "I want to know what exactly is SMIL"? => read the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/SMIL/

"why its required and how they can be integrated into a javascript application" => required by who or what?

"application architecture" => of what kind of software? A web site? A packaged App?

"What is its significance?" => "significance" means "the quality of being important" or "meaning": this clearly depends on what kind of application SMIL is used in.